# jQuery - How to make one element horizontally follow another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a box (leadBox) that follows the cursor.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    $('.leadBox').css({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY - $('.leadbox').height()/2
    });
})
```

Works perfectly. Now I have another box (followBox) that I want to follow leadBox, and only horizontally. My first instinct was to try...

```
var follow = $('.leadBox').offset();
    $('.followBox').css ({
    left: follow
});
```

But that doesn't do anything. Any ideas? Sorry my code is too basic and probably far off. I'm still a total amateur with java scripy and jQuery

Comment: you will likely need `display: inline-block` *(on both .leadBox and .followBox)* - though, without any HTML or CSS to go by, who knows

Comment: no, it's what the var is called

Comment: oops, sorry, about that, totally misread your code :p - the rest of my comment is valid though